# Condition for multiple variable (validating IP addresses)

Tags: linux, shell-script, ip

I have 5 variable

ex:

```
a, b, c, d, x,
```

if they are not between 1-255 (1-32 with x), echo an error message, or put in random text or character also echo an error message, how can I do that

exp:

```
echo "CIDR:"
read ip
x="$(echo $ip |cut -d "/" -f2)"
a="$(echo $ip |cut -d "." -f1)"
b="$(echo $ip |cut -d "." -f2)"
c="$(echo $ip |cut -d "." -f3)"
d="$(echo $ip |cut -d "." -f4 | cut -d "/" -f1)"
```

if ppl input wrong IP format like `1337.-135.abcxyz.!@#@#/12`3, it print out an error  message: `Error: wrong IP format` ...etc

Comment: yes they are all integers

Comment: are you required to use those variable names?  a lot of repetitious code could be eliminated by using an array.   e.g. `iparray=($(echo 192.168.1.15/32 | awk -F'[./]' -v OFS=" " '{$1=$1;$0=$0; print}') )`.   and to see the array `declare -p iparray`

Comment: or if you still wanted to `read` the ip address:    `IFS='./' read -r -a ip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use ipcalc to validate an IP addesss

> From man:
>
> ```
>  ipcalc - perform simple manipulation of IP addresses
> ```

example

```
ipcalc -cs 192.168.1.1/30 && echo OK || echo NOT_OK
```

or

```
ipcalc -cs "$a.$b.$c.$d/$x" && echo OK || echo NOT_OK
```

or

```
ipcalc -cs "$ip" && echo OK || echo NOT_OK
```

Comment: is there anyway not using it, my teacher didn's allow me to use thing like nmap and ipcalc ...etc

Comment: @LêMinhQuân From the point of view of _teaching_, not using tools that does this for you makes sense. From the point of actually performing the test in a real world situation, writing your own IP address parser is madness. You should update your question with the restrictions that are imposed and mention that this is a school assignment.

Answer (score -1):

you can use regex for ip check something like this

```
\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
 (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
 (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
 (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

> https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html

Comment: This does not fulfil the criteria that the last number should be in the range 1 to 32. It also fails to use the variables provided.